# Swagger not working if CORS enabled in Spring Webflux

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, spring-webflux, springfox

I have integrated swagger with spring webflux with below steps:

- added gradle dependency

> implementation("io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT")

- declared Docket bean

import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2WebFlux

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2WebFlux
class SpringFoxConfig {

    @Bean
    fun api(): Docket {
        return Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build()
    }

}
```

declared controller with swagger annotations

```
import io.swagger.annotations.Api
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*

@RestController
@Api(value = "healthCheck", description = "API to check service heartbeat", tags = ["APIs"])
@RequestMapping("/spring/app")
class HealthCheckController {

    @RequestMapping(method = [RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST], value = ["/ping"])
    suspend fun ping(): String {
        return "I am alive!"
    }
}
```

Run the app and access url at /swagger-ui.html, it is showing swagger ui with rest endpoint

But it is showing white label error page with 404 when CORS are enabled with below code

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.CorsRegistry
import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.EnableWebFlux
import org.springframework.web.reactive.config.WebFluxConfigurer

@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
class WebConfig: WebFluxConfigurer
{
    //Refer: https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework
    override fun addCorsMappings(registry: CorsRegistry)
    {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*") // any host or put domain(s) here
                .allowCredentials(false).maxAge(3600);
//                .allowedMethods("GET, POST") // put the http verbs you want allow
//                .allowedHeaders("Authorization") // put the http headers you want allow
    }
}
```

Can someone help what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you calling Swagger as a GET, POST, PUT, etc?   Also looks like your registry mapping is hijacking all requests ".addMapping("/**")"   So no way for a request to get to Swagger end point.

Comment: Swagger 2.3 does not support webflux, there is currently a snapshot version 3 of swagger that has webflux support

Comment: @ThomasAndolf i am using swagger 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT only

Comment: there is too little information, please produce a working example